# Saving (converting) raster objects in R?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, r, convert, export

I want to save my raster plot that produced with R to ArcGIS raster (.img, .tif and ASCII) file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have a look at `?writeRaster` from the `raster` package. Depending on the desired output format, just edit the format argument ("GTiff" for .tif, "HFA" for .img, and "ascii" for ESRI .asc). Here's some sample code,

```
writeRaster(yourRasterObject, "outputFilename", format = "GTiff")
```